# Checking for tag duplicates with jekyll excludes tags that are contained in other tags

Tags: arrays, tags, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to build a (simple, unweighted) tag cloud with liquid in my jekyll site. The tag cloud renders fine when I use this code:

```
{% assign sitetags = "" %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% for tag in page.tags %}
        {% unless sitetags contains tag %}
            {% assign sitetags = sitetags | append:tag | append:', ' %}
        {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %} 

{% assign sitetags = sitetags | split:', ' | sort %}
{% for tag in sitetags %}
    {% capture tag_name %}{{ tag }}{% endcapture %}
    <div>
        <a href="/tag/{{ tag_name }}">{{ tag_name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, there is one issue: if the name of a tag is contained within another tag, it won't show up in the tag cloud. For example, "art" is contained in "art-history" so it does not show up. In order to deal with this, I tried to fix it, however, it is not working. Here is my code:

```
{% assign sitetags = "" %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% for tag in page.tags %}
        {% if sitetags contains tag %}
            {% assign sitetags = sitetags | split:', ' %}
            {% assign truetag = true %}
            {% for taggo in sitetags %}
                {% if taggo != tag %}
                    {% continue %}
                {% else %}
                    {% assign truetag = false %}
                    {% break %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if truetag == true %}
                {% assign sitetags = sitetags | append:tag | append:', ' %} 
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% assign sitetags = sitetags | append:tag | append:', ' %}         
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %} 

{% assign sitetags = sitetags | split:', ' | sort %}
{% for tag in sitetags %}
    {% capture tag_name %}{{ tag }}{% endcapture %}
    <div>
        <a href="/tag/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The reason I am attempting it this way as opposed to just using site.tags is because I have articles/essays in other directories that I am trying to include. When I use site.tags, it only includes the tags that are on the blog posts but not the essays. Essentially, my site has both regular blog posts under /_blog and also essays in a different location, but I want to aggregate the tags of all of these in the same tag cloud.

I would really appreciate advice on what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out myself actually. Part of the issue was in initializing the array, so I ended up working with a string instead because I just couldn't get the arrays to work for some reason. I skipped over initialization and went straight to adding items to it. After that all I had to do was just run the uniq filter and it filtered out all the duplicates, so I didn't have to do any string comparison or anything like that.

Here is the solution:

```
{% for post in site.pages %}
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        {% assign tagcloud = tagcloud | append:tag | append:', ' %}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %} 

{% assign tagcloud = tagcloud | split:", " | uniq | sort %}

{% for tag in tagcloud %}
    {% capture tag_name %}{{ tag }}{% endcapture %}
    <div>
        <a href="/tag/{{ tag_name }}">{{ tag_name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a string to store your tags, you can use an array.

```
{% assign sitetags = "" | split:"" %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% if page.tags.size %}
    {% assign sitetags = sitetags | concat: page.tags %}
    {{ sitetags | inspect }} <br>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign sitetags = sitetags | sort | uniq %}
{{ sitetags | inspect }} <br>

{% for tag in sitetags %}
  <div>
    <a href="/tag/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This answer could use an explanation for why it's an improvement to use an array. (I think it has something to do with the way `contains` works for looking things up in the string used in the questioner's code, but I think the answer would be more educational if it spelled things out.)

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't work, got weird garbled mess output. I can't find any liquid documentation about the inspect filter.

Comment: `inspect` is a jekyll filter, you can use it to debug by seeing what's happening behind the scene.